# Integrate tesseract with cocos2d-x framework

Tags: android, c++, ios, cocos2d-x, tesseract

has anyone a clue how to add tesseract OR another similar library to cocos2d-x and pass DrawNode drawing to it so it'd be able to read handwriting?

Comment: is this ios or android question?

Comment: cocos2d-x so it's multiplatform, basically I use both.

Comment: There's doc (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki) about including tesseract, so you PROBABLY will be able pass some data from DrawNode to lib

Comment: Saving to png and passing to the lib is some idea, but probably it'll be slow.